# Chart.js Undesired Tooltip Showing Up for Legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a `tooltip` function that helps me display information from my chart in a different way than stock. So far it has worked great for me, however Its causing a tooltip to be displayed for the legend. I would like to keep that from being displayed while keeping the click functions for the different keys.

Here is my `tooltips` found under `options`

```
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    if((tooltipItem.yLabel) >= 1000000){
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": $" + money_round((tooltipItem.yLabel)/1000000)+" M";
                    }else if((tooltipItem.yLabel) >= 1000){
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": $" + money_round((tooltipItem.yLabel)/1000)+" K";
                    }else{
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": $" + (tooltipItem.yLabel);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

[image]

Also I am looking for a way to have the `tooltips` displayed to the left of the hovered item AND/OR decrease the distance from the cursor to the item that displays the `tooltip` so as to prevent having a `tooltip` pop up when not desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the tooltips position you can use `xAlign: 'right'` but then you have to be sure there's enough space on the left side of the chart because the tooltip will always be displayed on the left side of the point.

"Decrease the distance from the cursor to the item that displays the tooltip" is not possible when you use `intersect: false` because it will always display a tooltip with this option.

I would use `intersect: true` (or simply omit it because that's the default) combined with an increased hit radius for events like tooltip.

```
elements: {
  point: {
    hitRadius: 20
  }
},
```

[Here's a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zitusukefu/1/edit?html,js,output) to demonstrate these options.